# Variable in data-ng-init is not initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**What I have:** The following code is a very simple example to show a list of items using the `ng-repeat` directive. However, the only thing that shows up when opening the site is `{{product}}`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Some Title</title>

    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
<body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div 
        data-ng-repeat="product in products" 
        data-ng-if="$index % 3 == 0" 
        data-ng-init="products=['soda','beer','water','milk','wine']" class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4"
             data-ng-repeat="product in products.slice($index, ($index+3 > products.length ? products.length : $index+3))"> {{product}}</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Error in the console:** This is what's shown in the console. Not sure why the app is not configured properly as it is set in the html tag.

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

**Actual question:** Why is the variable `product` not containing an item from the list?

**What I tried so far:** A lot but I'm totally new to JavaScript so I can't say how to further proceed from here.

Comment: What is an error in your console. Press F12 and see console tab.

Comment: Paste your Controller or Javascript code.

Comment: you missed to add `app.js` where `myApp` module code lies..

Comment: you need to paste all your javascript and html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you didnt wire up an angular app. I assume you do not have any controllers or even an application in a javascript file. At the minimum you will need to do the below line of code

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Comment: Just tried to add this in the HTML file in a script tag but this doesn't work. Is it required to separate the JS part from the HTML file? `<script>var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);</script>`

Comment: it is not required to be in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting up the angular application itself, another problem is, that the `ng-repeat` is evaluated before the `ng-init`.

The `ng-repeat` specifies the instances of the element (the `div`) that should be created. After creation, for each of them the `ng-init` is evaluated. Initially there are no products so there is no element created at all and therefore `ng-init` won't be called at all.

One solution to that would be to put the `ng-init` into a parent element like the your container `div`. But usually you would want to put such code in your controller and avoid using `ng-init`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not having declaration of angular module then you don't need to write name of app i.e. `myApp`

See working [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/24867/)

I'm not getting what you're trying to achieve by slice in products. It may possible that you need to use angular filter to achieve that. Explain in detail what exactly you want to achieve to get help from folks.

Comment: Sry for that slicing stuff. I actually want to show a list of items horizontally (3 items), and then expand vertically (so 3 items per row). I guess it would have been easier for this example to just say i want to print the products. So instead of this `<div ... ` let's just say the code says `<div data-ng-repeat="product in products">{{product}}</div>`